# Multiverse fictional constraints

Tags: multiverse

In a multiverse the only thing that does not exist is fiction - true / false ?

Specifically is anything fictional ever written (Star Wars, Harry Potter, Last and First Men etc etc) actually non fiction in an infinite multiple universe ?

If false what are the boundary conditions of non-fiction ?

Comment: By fiction you mean fiction in writing or is there a physical terminology I have never heard? If there is, please provide a link, because I can't hear, if there isn't:

Comment: Martin, the reference to fiction was the normal definition, the question I find intriguing is that I suspect there is a limit to uncertainty principle generally communicated interpretation such as "the air in this room theoretically could move to one side and you would suffocate" etc and there are more extreme examples "a black hole appeared and floated above my head" or other such nonsense that could not be possible at all - or could they ? Mark

Comment: No, definitely not. In all theories I know every universe must abide to its laws of physics - they may be different from ours, but they are limiting rules. Most of fiction violates laws of physics (it is sometimes explicitly stated that violations of physics occur). Anything more than this answer would be pure speculation.

Comment: Yes but the devils in the detail don't you think? e.g. What constitutes violating the laws of physics given that there is a theoretical (if extremely small) probability that all the particles that make up a broom stick could actually float above the earth (an earth) and continue to do so as if by magic....

Comment: Multiverse just means any scenario with more than one universe. Two is more than one, so the "theory" that reality consists of "this universe" plus "Dragonball Z" is a multiverse theory, though not a popular one outside of Dragonball fandom... As for the many-worlds interpretation of QM, that's always relative to some specific theory like "standard model + gravity"... "All logically possible worlds exist" is multiverse maximalism, found e.g. in David Lewis and Max Tegmark, and is far beyond the limited multiverse notions that are employed by some physicists.

Comment: Martin, There has to be some rules here somewhere that acknowledge uncertainty principle potential for completely unrealistic events and some form of boundary ?

Comment: By multiverse I mean infinate possible universes, so the question is all about the word "possible".

Comment: I guess I could another (leading) question such as : is it theoretically possible for the Harry Potter stories to be true in some other universe (assuming there are many / infinite number) ?